# Encrypt data being sent and received by my C++ application?

Tags: c++, c, encryption, cryptography, network-security

Say I have a C / C++ application, and I wish to have it make requests via http, and receive responses, how might I choose to encrypt the data that is going / in or out? I can worry about decryption on either end later, for now I would like to get the encryption side of this.

Comment: First learn basics of `C`/`C++`, basics of socket programming, basics of `HTTP` protocol. Then move on to encryption which am not familiar with.

Comment: isn't https an option?

Comment: cool , so go ahead , what is stopping yopu , before interpreting http data which is mostly in text , decrypt after tcp before http layer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transport Layer Security (TLS 1.0, 1.1, 1.2) is a pretty standard protocol to use. You'll find quite a domain of open source libraries and OS-level APIs that support this protocol. This is, however, the issue. OS X, for instance, you'll have to leverage this through Transport Security; which is a completely different API than that on Windows, GNU/Linux, so forth.

Comment: Thanks for the actual productive reply, rather than the insult that Krishna felt was a viable reply.

Comment: No problem; I've done the same, especially when I only needed it for a web socket or something.

Answer (score 0):

`Say I have a C / C++ application, and I wish to have it make requests via http, and receive responses, how might I choose to encrypt the data that is going / in or out? I can worry about decryption on either end later, for now I would like to get the encryption side of this.`

Say we already have libraries like `OpenSSL`(for encryption and decryption) and `cURL`(according to your requirment). Try those.

Do some google search and try, if you didnt get your result, we`ll help you. Enjoy coding.